# How to extract text outside the <tag> using rvest package in R

Tags: html, r, web-crawler, rvest

Can someone help me extract the test that is after the *From*, I want to extract the sender name. It is situated right outside the em tag. I'm using the python BeautifulSoup package.

Here is a link to the webpage: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/0

I was able to extract the email title successfully since is was in a  tag. There are no other div's or classes in the html page.

This is the html code of the page:
[image: HTML Snippet]

Here is what I've tried

```
url <- "http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/0"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T, trim = T,      addAttributeNamespaces = T, encoding = "utf-8")

pre_text1 <- unlist(xpathSApply(doc, "//em",xmlValue))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract it with the following `xpath`

```
require(rvest)
doc <- read_html("http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/0")
doc %>% 
  html_node(xpath = "/html/body/table[2]//tr[1]/td[2]/table//tr/td/text()[6]") %>% 
  html_text
```

Result: `: Uğur Cihan KOÇ <u.cihan.koc () gmail com>`

How did i get there?
[image]
Starting from Chrome -> Right click on the text-element -> Copy -> Copy XPath.
Somehow there is no "copy selector". So i guess you cannot access this element by a pure css-selector.

This xpath looks as follows:

```
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/text()[1]
```

Rvest does not return any elements with this xpath. Somehow the `tbody`-part is not recognized (dont know why). Cutting it out and dropping the trailing `[1]`

```
/html/body/table[2]//tr[1]/td[2]/table//tr/td/text()
```

Gives you the result you need. Then you can select the 6th element either in xpath by adding `[6]` as i did or filtering in **R**.

Comment: How did you know that it was the 6th element ? Is there a way to traverse through all the elements returned ?

Comment: `doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/table[2]//tr[1]/td[2]/table//tr/td/text()")`. Go for `html_nodes` instead of `html_node` and drop the `[6]`